# Map entity to JSON using JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net, json

My entities are like this:

```
class Address
{
     public string Number { get; set; }
     public string Street { get; set; }
     public string City { get; set; }
     public string Country { get; set; }
}

class Person
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int Age { get; set; }
     public Address PostalAddress { get; set; }
}

Person newPerson = 
    new Person()
    {
       Name = "Kushan",
       Age = 25,
       PostalAddress = 
           new Address()
           {
               Number = "No 25",
               Street = "Main Street",
               City = "Matale",
               Country = "Sri Lanka"
           }
    };
```

Now I wanna map this newPerson object into JSON object like this,

```
{ 
     "PER_NAME" : "Kushan",
     "PER_AGE" : "25",
     "PER_ADDRESS" : {
                          "ADD_NUMBER" : "No 25",
                          "ADD_STREET" : "Main Street",
                          "ADD_CITY" : "Matale",
                          "ADD_COUNTRY" : "Sri Lanka"
                     }
}
```

Note: Above is just an example.

What I need is, I need to customize the Key at the serializing time. by default it is taking property name as the key. I can't change property names. How to do this?

Also, is it possible to change to order of appearing key-value pairs in JSON obj.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `DataContract` attributes to your classes and `DataMember` to the properties. Set `Name` property of `DataMemeber` attribute to your custom property name and `Order` property to define the order.

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember(Name = "PER_NAME", Order = 1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "PER_AGE", Order = 2)]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "PER_ADDRESS", Order = 3)]
    public Address PostalAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
var newPerson = new Person()
{
    Name = "Kushan",
    Age = 25,
    PostalAddress = new Address()
    {
        Number = "No 25",
        Street = "Main Street",
        City = "Matale",
        Country = "Sri Lanka"
    }
};

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Person));
ser.WriteObject(stream, newPerson);
```

To check the result:

```
var result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(stream.ToArray());

{"PER_NAME":"Kushan","PER_AGE":25,"PER_ADDRESS":{"ADD_NUMBER":"No 25","ADD_STREET":"Main Street","ADD_CITY":"Matale","ADD_COUNTRY":"Sri Lanka"}}
```

Comment: @AlexAza 
If I want to map `{"Age":25,"Name":"Kushan","PostalAddress":{"City":"Matale","Country":"Sri Lanka","Number":"No 25","Street":"Main Street"}}` into the class then ?

Comment: The question asks for JavaScriptSerializer and not DataContractJsonSerializer. I believe your answer is misleading without providing any relevant information regarding JavaScriptSerializer.

Answer (score 3):

You can serialize an anonymous type with JavaScriptSerializer, so you might try projecting your object into the shape you want to serialize:

```
person.Select(s => new { PER_NAME = s.Name, PER_AGE = s.Age });
```

Comment: Thanks gibson.. but Alex's ans is the most cleared one.. I accepted it.. :)