# How to deserialize and get the object and its array keys and values

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, javascriptserializer

I have the following JSON assigned to the variable `strP`:

```
{"get_the_data":[{"when_date":"09/12/2019","which_loc":"Orlando","who_witness":"visitor"}]}
```

And I need to generate the following output:

```
get_the_data:
    when_date - 09/12/2019
    which_loc - Orlando
    who_witness - visitor
```

How can I deserialize this JSON so as to get the KEY and the VALUE of each array within the object?  Here is what I have tried so far:

```
string object1, string array1;
var jsonObj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RO>(strP);
//get the parent key: 'get_the_data'
object1 = get_the_data.ToString();
foreach (var p in strP._data)
{
    //how can I get the KEY and the VALUE of each array within the object
    array1 += p.Key + " - " + p.Value + Environment.NewLine; //e.g. when_date - 09/12/2019
}

Console.WriteLine(object1 + ":" + Environment.NewLine + array1);
//...
public class Data1
{
    public string when_date { get; set; }
    public string which_loc { get; set; }
    public string who_witness { get; set; }
}

public class RO
{
    public List<Data1> _data { get; set; }
}
```

p.s. I am wanting to avoid using external JSON library and use native C# methods.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you have against using Json.net? It's incredibly mature and the number one downloaded package on Nuget. You're creating **so** much more work for yourself by avoiding it

Comment: Nothing really but wanted to do it natively... but I will check it out :) Thanks.

Comment: I think for most .Net developers (and even internally at Microsoft) Json.net is considered the "native" json solution. It ships by default with a ton of Microsoft templates especially around asp.net

Comment: If I am already using native javascriptdeserializer by default and importing JSON.net break anything?

Comment: No, it shouldn't break anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking to get the keys and values from the JSON without hardcoding the key names in advance, you can deserialize to a `Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>>`:

```
var jsonObj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>>>(strP);

string indent = "   ";
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var outerPair in jsonObj)
{
    sb.Append(outerPair.Key).AppendLine(":");
    outerPair.Value.SelectMany(d => d).Aggregate(sb, (s, p) => s.Append(indent).Append(p.Key).Append(" - ").AppendLine(p.Value));
}

Console.WriteLine(sb);
```

Incidentally, your `RO` type cannot be used to deserialize the JSON shown in your question because the name of its property:

```
public List<Data1> _data { get; set; }
```

differs from the property name in the JSON:

```
{"get_the_data":[ ... ] }
```

These property names need to match since `JavaScriptSerializer` does not have built-in support for renaming of properties during (de)serialization.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487483/javascriptserializer-custom-property-name) for details.

Comment: I like the LINQ method. Thanks. I will test and let you know how it went.

Comment: I get this error: `Type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b89],[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b89],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b89]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b89]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b89]]' is not supported for deserialization of an array.`

Comment: @Si8 - that will happen if your actual JSON contains an array -- an ordered sequence of values surrounded by `[` and `]` -- rather than an object -- an unordered set of key/value pairs surrounded by `{` and `}`.  Can you post your actual JSON?  Is it more complex than the JSON you show?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v9o91bm5/1/ The HTML is what I would like to retrieve from the Json. The key/value are both dynamic so I would like to be pulled from the Json itself.

Comment: @Si8 - I just ran the code from the answer using your new example, and for output I got `samp_data:
   value_1 - 09/12/2019
   value_2 - Leg
   value_3 - New York
   value_4 - 0000999201
   value_5 - Side
   value_6 - Test
   value_7 - 540-090-3443`, which is what you want.  There was no exception.  If you can provide a [mcve] that doesn't work, I can try to help, because at this point the question seems answered.