# Post json Object which property name has space to third party api from c#

Tags: c#, json, post, serialization, deserialization

I'm calling third party api from my asp.net mvc project. That api requires json object that has property name with space. But in c# we can't create property name with space. How Can I do that, I'm stuck?

I have tried using JsonProperty, but It  is not working. I have tried to replace string in serialize string and then send that string to api but that gives me total error.

```
{
 "Single":14000,
 "Double":14500,
 "Triple":15000,
 "ExtraBed":15500,
 "ExtraChild":16000,
 "ExtraAdult":16000
}
```

But instead of ExtraBed, I have to pass as 'Extra Bed'.

Comment: Have you tryed [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Extra Bed")]?

Comment: I'd use [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for a clean and uncomplicated solution

Comment: What do you use for serialization?. Could you please provide more code? Looks like serialization ignore your attribute.Show how you make serialization

Comment: @BasilKosovan : yes I have tried that also

Comment: [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Extra Bed")]
public decimal ExtraBed { get; set; }var p = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(_AxisRoom);


                        AxisRoom _hotelnew = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AxisRoom>(p);

Comment: @ScottyDoesKnow : I use but in get api, like in response property name is changed but this is about post api request

Comment: @dev_la , GET, POST doesn't matter . This is just about serialising/deserialsing

Comment: `JavaScriptSerializer` doesn't support renaming of properties, see [JavaScriptSerializer - custom property name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32488106/3744182).

Answer (score 5):

`JsonPropertyAttribute` doesn't impact on `JavaScriptSerializer`. There is no attribute for `JavaScriptSerializer` in order to change property name.You can write a custom `JavaScriptConverter` for it, but I recomend just use `Newtonsoft`.

```
 class AxisRoom
 {
     [JsonProperty("Extra Bed")]
     public decimal ExtraBed { get; set; }
 }


 AxisRoom _AxisRoom = new AxisRoom { ExtraBed = 3 };
 var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_AxisRoom);
```

`result` is equal to `{"Extra Bed":3.0}`