# Deserialize json where an attribute has the same name as a built in datatype, in C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I faced a problem that I could not find any solution to by google...

```
   JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
   MyClass myObject = js.Deserialize<MyClass>(jsonstring);
```

What about if an attribute in the json data is called "short"?
I cannot make a class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public int A;        
   public int B;       
   public int short;
}
```

So how can I get the jsonstring into an object in an easy way?
Very thankful for all help I can get.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScriptSerializer - custom property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487483/javascriptserializer-custom-property-name) and specifically [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32488106/1797425) answer...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@` in

```cs
public class MyClass
{
   public int A;        
   public int B;       
   public int @short;
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify in your answer what `@` means in this context?

Answer (score 1):

`short` is a keyword ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/); you will need to call the variable something else. `Short` would work just fine since keywords are case sensitive, and all keywords are lowercase.

In [@Balastrong's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69844782/3025856):

```cs
public class MyClass
{
   public int A;        
   public int B;       
   public int @short;
}
```

The `@` symbol is being used as a "verbatim identifier" ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim);
see number 1). This allows the interpreter to understand `@short` as the *identifier* `short` instead of the *keyword* `short`.

Hope this cleared some things up.