# C# - how to use invalid characters in a variable name

Tags: c#, json

In C#, I'm building a class (simplified here for discussion purposes) that eventually will be serialized into some externally defined JSON:

```
    { 
    "$schema": "http://example.com/person.json",
    "name": "John",
    "age": 86
    }
```

In my code I would have something like:

```
public class Person
{
    public const string $schema= @"http://example.com/person.json";
    public string name {get;set; }
    public int age {get; set;}
}
```

...

```
 Person person = new Person();
 person.name = "John";
 person.age = 88;

 JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 string json = serializer.Serialize(person);
```

In my code above the $schema is causing an "Unexpected character '$' error.  Is there a workaround?

Comment: Nope. C# simply has different variable naming rules than JavaScript. You could, of course, always use a dictionary that maps strings to objects, though I recommend against it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Map entity to JSON using JavaScriptSerializer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398171/map-entity-to-json-using-javascriptserializer)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Provide the attribute `[DataContract]` to your `Person` class.

Also, did you mean to make `schema` `const`?

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember(Name = "$schema")]
    public string schema { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: You need to turn `schema` into a property.  Serialization doesn't work on fields, as far as I can remember.

Comment: Does using DataContract mean I need to use a different serializer?  I don't get the $schema in my json if I change just my Person class to what is indicated here.

Comment: Assuming you're using `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json` no. However you didn't specify what serializer you were using so I assumed the one provided here. You can use `DataContractJsonSerializer`.

Comment: If you use DataMember along with DataContract attribute, you will have to decorate all members, not just the one which had an invalid name. At least this was the case in .NET CORE 2 preview with VS 2017 TC preview 5. So JsonProperty solved the issue for me as it had no such requirements. I could now only decorate the property with an invalid name .

Answer (score 6):

If using JSON.NET, you can use the [`JsonProperty`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) attribute:

```
public class Person {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$schema")]
    public string schema {get; set;} = @"lsjdhflsjkdf";

    public string name {get;set;}
}
```